# F# forcing a user to input an integer

Tags: validation, input, f#

Lets say I was to read in a user's input with the following:

```
let input = Console.ReadLine()
```

How would I validate a user's input so that it has to be an integer else an error message is displayed?

Comment: you could pattern match on the input with `Int32.TryParse`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on @s952163's comment a bit.

You could validate in a typical fashion like so:

```
let parse (s: string) =
    match (System.Int32.TryParse(s)) with
    | (true, value) -> value
    | (false, _) -> failwith "Invalid int"
```

Note that this function has a return type of int as well as an implicit return type of an exception.

A more idiomatic way of parsing an integer would be a pure function:

```
let parse (s: string) =
    match (System.Int32.TryParse(s)) with
    | (true, value) ->  Ok value
    | (false, _) -> Error "Invalid int"
```

This function has a return type of Result meaning that all inputs map to an explicit output.

Bigger programs can then be composed from functions consuming only the cases when the input can be parsed with combinators from the Result module (like map and bind).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/results

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use Active Patterns to handle parsing in F#.  You can create an Active Pattern for each type you want to parse, such as:

```
let (|Int32|_|) (str: string) =
    match Int32.TryParse(str) with
    | (true, value) -> Some value
    | _ -> None
```

You can create a similar Active Pattern for Int64, Bool, DateTime, etc.  Then, you can use them as such:

```
match Console.ReadLine() with 
| Int32 i -> printfn "Integer: %d" i 
| invalid -> printfn "Error: %s is not an Integer" invalid
```